# "composer update" gives UnexpectedValueException

Tags: composer

Locally, I first tried to update core individually using `composer update drupal/core drupal/core-recommended --with-all-dependencies`. This gave an error,  so I just used `composer update`, which usually works. With that, I got the following error.

Installing drupal/core failed and the command raised the following exception.

> [UnexpectedValueException]
> 'C:\wamp64\www\tantrayonimassage/vendor/composer/tmp-6c1ec2df3485bdc02d3abaf470e0d9a8' is not a zip archive.

Command line extract after `composer update`:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies Nothing to modify in lock file Installing
> dependencies from lock file (including require-dev) Package
> operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> - Downloading drupal/core (8.9.12)
> - Installing drupal/core (8.9.12): Extracting archive
>   Install of drupal/core failed
>
> [UnexpectedValueException]
> 'C:\wamp64\www\tantrayonimassage/vendor/composer/tmp-9df4569ff8e2fe46b4f5073516e8122d'
> is not a zip archive.
>
> update [--with WITH] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run]
> [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-install] [--no-autoloader]
> [--no-scripts] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [-w|--with-dependencies]
> [-W|--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
> [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
> [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX]
> [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs]
> [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs]
> [--] []...

This is my composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 8 projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "drupal/commerce": "^2.21",
    "drupal/commerce_email": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/commerce_mollie": "^1.6",
    "drupal/commerce_shipping": "^2.0@RC",
    "drupal/commerce_stock": "^1.0@alpha",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^8.8",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^8.8",
    "drupal/swiftmailer": "^2.0@beta",
    "drupal/webform": "^5.23"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "public_html/"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "public_html/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "public_html/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "public_html/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "public_html/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "public_html/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "public_html/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "public_html/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please don't add screenshots of command line output. Please simply copy/past it and format it accordingly using blockquote and code highlighting. For Composer-related questions it's also necessary that you add your composer.json contents to the question. Many thanks 

Comment: I think you are better off running `$ composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-dependencies` since your composer.json doesn't contain a `drupal/core` dependency. But the error you get with the ZIP... Maybe try `$ composer clearcache`. Sounds more of a Composer on Windows issue. Try everything from https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/1242. Maybe also change `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to `"minimum-stability": "stable"` but that's [something different](https://www.drupal.org/node/3174472).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I tried doing a cache clear, but that didn't help.
While trying some more things, I also did an upgrade to the latest composer version. After doing that, for some reason it worked...